# Unable to Build and Update new version of IOS Because of PLA Update available and No signing certificate "IOS Distribution" found

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I want to update my IOS app in the Appstore, while building new version and uploading I get this error:

[image: The Error screenshot]

The Error Message:

> The following errors occurred while locating and generating signing assets. Xcode is unable to resolve these issues automatically. • Unable to process request - PLA Update available You currently don't have access to this membership resource. To resolve this issue, agree to the latest Program License Agreement in your developer account. % No signing certificate "¡OS Distribution" found No "¡OS Distribution" signing certificate matching team ID "-----------" with a private key was found.

How should I fix it?

I've Tried to update the Xcode but nothing happed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying to update the Xcode version(but Noting happened), I found out
This problem happens because you have to accept new Agreement on the Account of Apple Developer.
If you go to [yourAccount](https://developer.apple.com/account) you will see that, you have a message at the top and you have to accept the new Agreement to solve this issue.
And you can see the Agreements list on the Agreement tab:

[image]

This is what I had to Accept to continue building and uploading the ipa.
Remember that these Agreements are shown once in a while.

Happy Coding...

Answer (score 0):

Your App account owner should sign in at developer.apple.com with their Apple ID and accept the latest developer's agreement